# Very specific regular expressions inside of for loop R

Tags: regex, rstudio, grepl, exact-match

I am trying to run a for loop through 39 categories using grepl. The strings I am trying to match have a lot of overlap in the words they use. I am not very experienced with regular expressions and find that non of the anchors or grouping mechanisms I'm using are working in the slightest.

First I begin by writing out my expressions in an excel file and importing them into R Studio via read.delim.

```
reg.ex <- read.delim("combined_codes.csv", sep = ",")
```

Some of the categories I'm trying to match in the data base I have use the same words, but I want to keep as separate categories when I'm writing the csv files in the loop. Here is an example of the resulting data frame with some of the more complicated expressions. This is also the syntax I'm currently using to match with grepl.

```
 EXPRESSION 

 STORAGE
 ^DIVERSION TO STORAGE$
 ^BASE FLOW$ [^STORAGE]
 ^BANKFULL FLOW$ [^STORAGE]
 ^MITIGATION$ [^BY]
 ^MITIGATION BY NON_USE$
 ^MITIGATION BY DELIVERY$
 [^RECHARGE FOR] [^SUB]IRRIGATION [^STORAGE]
 ^RECHARGE FOR IRRIGATION$
 ^SUBIRRIGATION$
 ADMINISTRATIVE
```

Here is a small subset of examples. There are many categories with "STORAGE" in their name I am trying to absorb into a larger Storage category. However, many categories have a storage category complementing them. E.G. BASE FLOW and BASE FLOW STORAGE are two categories I would like to keep separate, with BASE FLOW STORAGE being grouped into the larger STORAGE category. I am hoping by using [^STORAGE] that will remove storage categories. Additionally, BASE FLOW AND BANKFULL FLOW both have the word 'flow' in them, but they must remain separate. I am hoping that using ^ to begin the string and $ to end the string will keep those two categories separate, however that hasn't worked. The word FLOW occurs at least 10 times in other categories. Lastly, IRRIGATION is another category that can be easily complicated by other words. I am hoping using the same ^$[^] anchors, I can keep the last 3 rows their own separate category.

When I run the loop...

```
# rights.merge is data frame I am trying to subset via the expressions
# reg.ex.match is a vector of these expressions 

for(i in as.character(reg.ex.match)){
  sector.name <- subset(right.merge, grepl(paste(reg.ex.match, collapse = 
    "|"), as.character(rights.merge$Beneficial_Use)))

  file.name <- paste(out.directory, "USE_", i, ".csv", sep = "")
  write.csv(sector.name, file.name)
  print(file.name)
}
```

What is returned is a csv of multiple different Beneficial Uses and non have been the exact match I am trying to obtain.

I realize this is a commonly asked question, however I have yet to find an answer that helps me. Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If `^BANKFULL FLOW$ [^STORAGE]` is meant to be a regex pattern, note that it will never match any string. As a lot of other ""patterns" from above list.

Comment: Character sets (groups of characters surrounded by `[` and `]`), along with negated character sets (`[^ ... ]`), match *one* out of any of the characters they contain. So the pattern `[^STORAGE]` simply matches any character that is not A, E, G, O, R, S, or T, once.

Comment: If you want to match `BANKFULL FLOW` and not `BANKFULL FLOW STORAGE`, just use `^BANKFULL FLOW$`, not need to add anything else since it's asserting beginning/ending positions of the string